# @if dentro de @foreach donde esta el error?

Tags: laravel

Donde esta el error?? cuando la variable del **empty** viene llena funciona perfecto pero cuando viene vacía no me muestra la otra parte ni la imagen ni el enlace donde puede estar el error ??

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<div>
  @foreach($product->fphoto as $produ)
@if(empty($produ->id))
  <a href="{{ route('products.show', $product->id) }}">
            <img  src="{{asset('img/profile.jpg')}}" alt="">
              @else
                  <a href="{{ route('products.show', $product->id) }}">
              <img  src="{{ $produ->photo }}" alt="">

      @endif
      @endforeach
            <h3>{{ $product->nombreyape }}</h3></a>
            <p>Textop>
          </div>
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres controlar si viene el arreglo lleno o no y enviar un mensaje en consecuencia; deberías hacerlo a través de un `forelse`

**EJEMPLO**

```
@forelse($posts as $post)
    <h1>{{ $post->title }}</h1>
@empty
    <small>No existe contenido que mostrar</small>
@endforelse
```

justo después de `@empty` mandas el mensaje o las acciones que vas a llevar a cabo para indicar que el arreglo esta vacio y que por consecuencia el usuario haga algo

Comment: muchas gracias es perfecto